# AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular turning to helvetica in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

In iOS 8 we have no problem getting AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular or Light or Medium etc to show up but in iOS 7, despite the fact that the font was introduced in iOS 7.

In all my labels, it changes to Helvetica (system) instead.

Anyone know what I should do? Should I load it as a custom font?

Comment: @StuartCampbell, No. BUT I have a theory: Perhaps it's that in iOS 7 that's the way the font looks. I mean, it's a Korean language font. Maybe no one paid attention to the Roman characters until iOS 8. We replaced some stuff in iOS 7 with Roboto.

Comment: Looks like we are not the only ones with this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272856/cannot-set-uilabel-font-in-ios-7-not-using-custom-font
Very frustrating.