# Cannot set uilabel font in ios 7( not using custom font)

Tags: ios, ios7, fonts

Background:
font using: AppleSDGothicNeo-Light

ios supporting: ios7+

Issue:
I set the font for uilabel by:

```
self.lblName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-Light" size:12.f];
```

What I expected:
[image: character C at iosFonts.com]

What I got in iOS7(iOS8 is alright):

[image: Character C in iOS7]

When I want to print out the debug description, it got:
font-family: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt

what happened?

Comment: I finally end up with changing the font to custom font.....

Answer (score 2):

i hope it will help you..

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-Light size:12];
[yourLable setFont:myFont];
```

Comment: Thanks, however it can't.